# Runtime Error don't know at ALL what to do i have no experience with these things

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling, runtime-error

Who can help me with this?? I don't know what the hell to do at all. From begining to end I don't even know how to create a tag or nothing. help me? asap this is how it looks:

Server Error in '/HRX' Application. Runtime Error Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

```
Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote     machines, please create a tag within a "web.config" configuration file located     in the root directory of the current web application. This tag should then     have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Server Error in '/HRX' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error         settings for this application prevent the details of the application error     from being     viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be     viewed by browsers running     on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on     remote         machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config"         configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This         <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by     modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors>     configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: that error just says it can't show you the error and how to change your web config to show the error.  If you try testing this local you should get a better error.  we can't do anything with this

Answer (score 1):

If you have remote access to the server then try to browse the page on the server locally.

Otherwise try to set customerrors mode to "Off" and deploy it.

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

If you do either way you will hopefully see a Exception StackTrace instead. That will probably give you a better clue of what that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said, it helps to install some sort of error handling capabilities. For a nearly plug and play solution, look into [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) (which can be installed easily with NUGET). This keeps a database of all the unhandled exceptions in your ASP.NET site and can even email you the error details when a problem is encountered.

Also, you'll want to set up a [custom error page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs) that explains to your users an unexpected error has occurred. This looks much more professional.